# Login in a Java EE Application client doesn't work well

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to develop a Swing Application Client of a GlassFish Server. When I try to get my first instance of a container - protected EJB, my custom `CallbackHandler` is called, I introduce my credentials in my custom `JDialog` and all work well if the credentials are good.

The problem is that if I introduce bad credentials, I'm not prompted to introduce them again, I get a security exception every time I call a protected method.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The code is as follows:

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    bean=(JndiEJBRemote)ctx.lookup("java:global/JndiPrueba1/JndiPrueba1-ejb/JndiEJB");
    jTextField1.setText(bean.getUser());

}
```

Simply, when a JButton is pressed, an EJB is looked up for returning a "business" value, which is then assigned to a JTextField. The first time I click the button, the custom CallbackHandler is shown to retrieve the user/password, but on the next clicks, the CallbackHandler is not called, no matter if the credentials were right or wrong!

Comment: Please show us the relevant code

Comment: Done. The code is on the first post. Thanks for your support!